# Rails SQL query on unknown (dynamic) number of queries using LIKE

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-like

I have a Rails search form that performs a dynamic query. That is, the user enters a search like:

```
(hobby="skiing") OR (gender="male" AND hobby="jogging")
```

So, I don't know how many queries I will be searching by until runtime.

I parse the search query by converting it into a valid SQL query, so the above search would be converted to the following format:

```
query = "hobby LIKE ? OR (gender LIKE ? AND hobby LIKE ?)"
queries = ["skiing", "male", "jogging"]
```

For the following query:

```
where(query, queries)
```

However, the general syntax of the Rails search query is very limiting:

```
where(query, query_1, query_2, query_3)
```

I cannot replace the 'query_n' arguments with an array like I want to, without Rails throwing an error.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `where' for ["a", "b", "c"]:Array)
```

Attempting to [splat](http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-splat-array-manipulation-destructuring/) the array yields the same error:

```
where(query, *queries)
```

Again:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `where' for ["a", "b", "c"]:Array)
```

So what can I do?

EDIT:

The full search function looks like this:

```
def self.search(search)
    query = "%#{search}%"
    if search
        includes(:games, :jobs)
        strngs = ["hobby = ? OR name = ? OR gender = ?", "dsfgdsfg", "dsgsdfgsd", "sdfsfsdf"]
        .where(strngs)
```

Comment: Can you give a little more information as to what information is being sent through the search form (is each value assigned to its attribute?)? Also, are the queries in the array always in the correct order (att_1, att_2, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you'll want to do is pass an array as a single argument to `where` which contains both the query AND the dynamic values. For example:

```
where(["att_1 LIKE ? OR att_2 LIKE ?", "value1", "value2"])
```

If an array is passed as the first and only argument, then the first element of the array is treated as a template. The following array values are treated as the dynamic values for the query template.

For your example, instead of having two separate variables `queries` and `query`, combine them into one `query` variable:

```
# A single array with the query AND values
query = ["hobby LIKE ? OR (gender LIKE ? AND hobby LIKE ?)", "skiing", "male", "jogging"]

# Run the `where` with a single array as the argument
YourModel.where(query)
```

This will allow you to query the DB with an unknown number of values using `LIKE`.

> For reference: [Rails where() docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where)

Comment: This gave an error: NoMethodError (undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x000000032c6c90>):

Comment: Are you running `where` on an array? It should be ran on an ActiveRecord model

Comment: Put `strngs` above `includes` and then combine `includes().where()`. The `.where` (period before `where`) makes Ruby interpret it as you're connecting it to the `strngs` array directly above it